# Exceptions connection delay opening of the software

Tags: c#, wpf

I am having some problems to handle the connection to a database. What I did essentially was to create a class called `Database`, in this I placed all the methods required to connect to the database, check whether the connection is active and update a control depending on the status of the connection. This works well, control is updated and there are no problems, but when the connection on your computer is absent, the program delays its opening because they generated a series of exceptions in particular that:

> MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlException (0x80004005)

The exception occurs in the method `isAvailable()`, this method checks whether the connection is available or not, and returns true if there is, respectively, or false if it is absent.

```
public static bool isAvailable()
{
    try
    {
        string connStr = @"Server=xxx;Port=xxx;Database=xxx;Uid=xxx;Pwd=xxx;";
        connection = new MySqlConnection(connStr);
        connection.Open();     
        return true;
    }catch(Exception ex)
    {
       connection.Close();
       Console.WriteLine(ex.ToString());
       return false;
    }
}
```

This method is invoked by checkStatus that contains the following:

```
public static void checkStatus() 
{
    if(isAvailable() == false)
    {
        updateStatus("false");
    }
    else
    {
        updateStatus("true");
    }
}
```

checks whether it is true or false and returned respectively to the back passes the value to another method that simply brings up a warning Canvas red or green in the interface ...

`checkStatus` is called in every aspect of my other classes to check the connection status (before executing a query, pretty much the structure is as follows):

```
string stm = "SELECT * FROM history";
MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(stm, Database.Database.Connection);
Database.Database.checkStatus(); //here
MySqlDataReader rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
```

Within the class constructor call the method isAvailable Database to check if the connection is actually open or not.

At this point I do not understand why the exceptions while managing the program delays the appearance when the user executes it. If no exceptions occur when you start, the program takes about 5 seconds to boot, while with the exceptions I arrived at 1 minute!
What am I doing wrong?

Comment: This error number says: "Timeout expired."

Comment: Yeah, because the connection on my pc missing. I'm trying to execute this test to avoid the delay of boot.

Comment: This is the complete exception: MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlException (0x80004005): Unable to connect to any of the specified MySQL hosts.

Comment: Just a side note, but public methods in c# should start with capital letters. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229043.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Making a connection to the database server may take quite some time due to many factors: network conditions, server load, authentication overhead etc. Hence the driver (the code behind `MySqlConnection`) needs to wait an appropriate amount of time to decide whether the connection can or cannot be established. The default timeout is, apparently in your case, 60 seconds (or a multiple of the default 15 seconds as per documentation due to several requests?).

What you can do is lower the timeout by means of the `ConnectionTimeout` argument in the connection string — see the [documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-net/en/connector-net-connection-options.html) here. However, bear in mind that by setting it to, say, 5 seconds, you program may end up failing in legitimate cases where it would otherwise succcessfuly connect to the server. I suggest you perform database operations or at least the initial check asynchronously and display a 'please wait' message meanwhile.

Comment: Uhm the connection timeout didn't solve the problem apparently

Comment: @Bender Then debug your own code… There isn't more to tell based on the information you provided.